What is the relationship between the level set up in a chess machine and the ELO that the machine is playing at that level?
For example, I want to know what the ELO my Millenium chess genius pro is playing when I set up it at easy level 7.
Does anybody know that relationship?

There's no general formula to use. I would suggest playing it against other computers with known Elo ratings and seeing how it does.
